# Tablet two-pane UI - fragment error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

**What im trying to do :** Display a Tablet UI in a two-pane layout using the mainActivity/Fragment and the detailActivity/Fragment when using a tablet.

**Problem** - Im not sure I really have the tablet UI set up correctly. Followed android documentation to the best I could understand it but im getting an error inflating class fragment. Here is the relevant error message.

```
Process: com.rykuno.movietestapp, PID: 13502
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rykuno.movietestapp/com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                             at com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
```

I took a large break working on this app after a slight motorcycle accident and for some reason this is somewhat stumping me. 
If its more convenient for me to copy and paste the code please let me know! Thanks so much for any help!

Link to res directory - https://github.com/Rykuno/Flix-Viewer/tree/tablet/app/src/main/res

Link to activities - https://github.com/Rykuno/Flix-Viewer/tree/tablet/app/src/main/java/com/rykuno/movietestapp/Activities

Answer (score 0):

The following code in `layout-large/activity_detail.xml` is wrong:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentDetail"
    >
</fragment>
```

You haven't defined the fragment.

Looking at your `MainActivity` I think you want that to be a `FrameLayout` instead of static fragment.

Comment: Tried changing both to a FrameLayout and nothing shows. Currently I am able to see the gridView on the left half of the screen, Yet when i click on an item, it opens on a completely new screen.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to inflate the frgament if you are using frame layout in oncreate of your activity. In case you use a static fragment you must point the fragment class it is using in the form of

android:name="package name.classnameoffragment"
 tools:context="package name.classnameoffragment"

Comment: are you referring to the detailFragment?

Comment: @Rykuno 1) use layout-sw600dp for tablet 7 inch and higher. 2) In onCreate of mainActivity inflate the fragment. 3)Also the MainActivityFragment class in case of a two pane layout the onItemClick method should inflate the fragment instead of starting the activity. 4)You can accomplish this by creating an interface in MainActivityFragment as in Sunshine tutorials.5)For a two pane layout inflate the first movie detail by default.